# Estimating spatial autocorrelation from counts on linear network

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatstat

I'm working with count data sampled along roadways. I would like to estimate the spatial autocorrelation of the counts, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to incorporate the network structure of the roadways.

Consider for instance the `spiders` data set from `spatstat`, with a random count variable added (eggs maybe?):

```
set.seed(1)
spiders$data$count <- rpois(48, 10)
plot(spiders)
```

[image]

What would be the correct way to estimate spatial autocorrelation of counts along this network?

Comment: Are you asking *how* to compute the distance on a line network or are you asking if that is the correct distance measure to use in this case?

Comment: The latter. I'm wondering if there's a specific treatment that should be applied in the case of estimating point-on-network autocorrelation. If I were to calculate Moran's I for the example above, is it as simple as using the shortest path distance in the spatial weights matrix? Or is there some other formulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not one "correct" way. Choice of distance metric or weights in computing a single measure of spatial autocorrelation is up to you and becomes part of the hypothesis you are testing rather than a measure of some absolute idea of autocorrelation that might exist outside of a measure.

For example, if you use the distance along the line network, you are measuring correlation of some variable Z *with distance along the line network* and any hypothesis test against a null hypothesis of no autocorrelation is a test of no correlation *with distance along the line network*.

If you use Euclidean distance, that's a different autocorrelation measure. It could be similar or different to a Moran's I along the line network. They are different things and will have different values.

Which you use depends on which distance measure is most relevant to the process under consideration. Theoretically you should decide on this before you get the data since it forms part of your hypothesis, and if you try one distance measure and then another and pick the one with the largest Moran I then congratulations you've committed scientific fraud :) Well okay you can correct your significance level for multiple hypothesis tests but that's a whole other question.

But I'd say: if the thing you are moving is restricted to or is only transported along a line network - use the line network distance if the network is sparse enough that the network distance can be significantly different to the Euclidean distance. In a large urban area, for example, its unlikely to be sufficiently different to make any effect beyond the inherent noise in your data. In a rural area, perhaps where an urban centre is easy to get to from anywhere, but transport links between villages are minimal, or a landscape fractured by impassable lakes making direct routes hard, it might make a significant different.

Comment: Thanks, @spacedman. My purpose is just to test the null hypothesis that observations are independent along the network, so I will go with the line network distance. I can't seem to find any literature where counts along a network have been assessed for spatial autocorrelation (as points, rather than sums of observations along segments or as single occurrences), so this explanation was very helpful.